# Kivy/MD - How do I place an icon to the right of a text list item (with code and image) ..?

Tags: list, kivy, widget, icons, kivymd

I am trying to put an icon to the right hand side of a text list item, but this code below is giving me an error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`
at this line:  `items.add_widget(icon)`.
Here's what I want it to look like:
[List item with icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU6fx.jpg)

Here's my code.  It can be copied, and run as-is.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, IconRightWidget, MDList
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "400dp"
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: Mcontainer

MDFloatLayout:
'''
class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):
    
    def on_start(self):
    
        Mcontent=Content()
        for x in range(0,7):
            icon = IconRightWidget(icon="lock")
            items = OneLineIconListItem(text="This is a test")
            items.add_widget(icon)
            Mcontent.ids.Mcontainer.add_widget(items)
        
        self.MSetFileOptionsdialog = MDDialog(type="custom",content_cls=Mcontent,)
        
        self.MSetFileOptionsdialog.open()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Item>
    _txt_left_pad: "12dp"

    IconRightWidget:
        icon: root.icon


<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "400dp"

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: Mcontainer

MDFloatLayout:
'''


class Item(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        Mcontent = Content()

        for x in range(0, 7):
            items = Item(text="This is a test", icon="lock")
            Mcontent.ids.Mcontainer.add_widget(items)

        self.MSetFileOptionsdialog = MDDialog(type="custom", content_cls=Mcontent)
        self.MSetFileOptionsdialog.open()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```

Comment: Thanks.   It does look like ```OneLineIconListItem``` should work, but doesn't, and ```OneLineAvatarIconListItem``` is the one to use.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add widget to an Id from your `load_string` or `.kv` file, you can just use the following; this is to be done in the `.py` file. There are limitations if screens are involved.

```
self.root.ids.name_of_the_id_referenced_container_widget_or_layout.add_widget(the one you already have in your.kv file)
```